# document.getElementById is not working at all

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm a huge Norse mythology buff and am trying to make a Ragnarok countdown Chrome App. The code works fine on one editing website, and even when I put it in this post, but when I try to open it as an app, the document.getElementById to display the clock doesn't do anything, no matter what I do, and I've done everything. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}
body {
    color:white;
    background-color:gray;
</style>
    </head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
 window.onload = (function () {// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2099 12:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var years = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
    var days = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = years + "y" + days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Prepare for Ragnarok";
    }
}, 1000);});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'when I try to open it as an app?"

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed the mention of "Chrome App." I'm unfamiliar with how those work, so I'm not sure how to try to reproduce the issue. I've added the `google-chrome-app` tag, which will hopefully attract the right experts.

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy. I think your `<script>` tag may not be executing at all, and you may need to move your code to an external JavaScript file.

Comment: (That link is for extensions, but the Chrome App documentation suggests it applies here too: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.)

Comment: Inline js doesn't work in chrome apps/extensions. Use a separate file for js, don't alter CSP.

Comment: Thank you, I moved it to another file and it finally works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestions in comments are correct.  Move all the Javascript inside of your  tags to a separate file, say script.js.  Then replace your script tags with one that references the file:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```